# Getting lightning:select picklist value in controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller

hey i am trying to get a picklist value and want to multiply it with an integer number in lightning controller.I tried this code.

## Controller

```
({
    calculateAmount : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dalquantity=document.getElementById('gett');
        if(dalquantity!=0&&dalquantity!=NaN){
            var totaldalprice=60*dalquantity;
            component.set("v.resu",totaldalprice);
        }
    }
})
```

## Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="resu" type="integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="first" type="integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="getter" type="List" />
    <div><center><B><I>Apna Dhaba</I></B></center></div>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="background-color:Yellow">


    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
  <thead style="border-style: dotted">
    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Item">Item</div> 

      </th>
      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Unit price">Unit Price</div>
      </th>

      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Quantity">Quantity</div>
      </th>
      <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Final Amount">Final Amount</div>
      </th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
         <tbody>
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
      <th data-label="Item" scope="row">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Dal Makhani" >Dal Makhani</div>
        </th>
           <td>
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="60" value="{!first}">60{!first}</div>
            </td>
        <td>
     <div  class="w3-text-green" ><b>Number Of Quantity</b></div>

        <lightning:select name="changer" label=""  aura:id="gett"  onchange="{!c.calculateAmount}">
            <option value="" >Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1" >1</option>
            <option value="2" >2</option>
            <option value="3" >3</option>
            <option value="4" >4</option>
            <option value="5" >5</option>
            <option value="6" >6</option>
            <option value="7" >7</option>
            <option value="8" >8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </lightning:select>

            </td>

         <td>
        <div class="slds-truncate"  aura:id="dal">Rs.{!v.result}</div>

            </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way you'd do this is to bind value, as Brian said. You can then access the attribute directly via component.get. Here's your code, modified to use an attribute.

## Controller

```
({
    calculateAmount : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dalquantity = component.get("v.quantity") || 0;
            var totaldalprice=60*dalquantity;
            component.set("v.resu",totaldalprice);
    }
})
```

## Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="resu" type="integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="first" type="integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="getter" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="quantity" type="Integer" />
    <div><center><B><I>Apna Dhaba</I></B></center></div>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="background-color:Yellow">


        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
            <thead style="border-style: dotted">
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Item">Item</div> 

                    </th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Unit price">Unit Price</div>
                    </th>

                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Quantity">Quantity</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Final Amount">Final Amount</div>
                    </th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <th data-label="Item" scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Dal Makhani" >Dal Makhani</div>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="60" value="{!first}">60{!first}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div  class="w3-text-green" ><b>Number Of Quantity</b></div>

                        <lightning:select value="{!v.quantity}" name="changer" label=""  aura:id="gett"  onchange="{!c.calculateAmount}">
                            <option value="" >Choose your option</option>
                            <option value="1" >1</option>
                            <option value="2" >2</option>
                            <option value="3" >3</option>
                            <option value="4" >4</option>
                            <option value="5" >5</option>
                            <option value="6" >6</option>
                            <option value="7" >7</option>
                            <option value="8" >8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </lightning:select>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate"  aura:id="dal">Rs.{!v.resu}</div>

                    </td>
                </tr></tbody></table></div>
</aura:component>
```

---

Notice I added a "quantity" attribute, and bound it to your select list via its value attribute. From there, it's a simple matter to get the value from the attribute and do the math. Note that your markup also referred to "result", when it should have referred to "resu." This is corrected in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `value` attribute to `lightning:select` and bind it to an aura component attribute.  Then you can access the value when the `onchange` event fires

In the Aura Component:

```
    <aura:attribute name="selectedVal" type="Integer" />

    <lightning:select aura:id="gett" value="{! v.selectedVal }" name="changer" label="" onchange="{!c.calculateAmount}">
        <option value="" >Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <!-- All option values... -->
    </lightning:select>
```

JS Controller:

```
calculateAmount : function(component, event, helper) {
    const dalQuantity = component.find("gett").get("v.value");   // Or use event.getParam("value");
    if (!$A.util.isEmpty(dalQuantity)){
        const totalDalPrice = 60 * dalQuantity;
        component.set("v.result",totalDalPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not getting desire result it is showing NaN in result

Comment: Typo - try using `component.find("gett").get("value");` to get the actual value

Comment: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:Bill_Generator$controller$calculateAmount [Invalid key value]
Failing descriptor: {c:Bill_Generator$controller$calculateAmount} .Getting this error on trying component.find("gett").get("value");

Comment: Typo AGAIN, sorry!  Need `v.value` - `component.find("gett").get("v.value");